# How to get user profile from id_token through API call

Tags: api, backend, google-authentication

I have an API that a applications uses, the application sends me a id_token of a already authenticated user or Google accounts.

How can I make a API call (not java script call) in ASP.net to the google API server to get the users profile information such as name, so that I can save the user in the DB for the application.

I already have a google project with a Client ID and client secret.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to though asp.net API get the user information that I wanted.

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var uri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=" + ACCESSTOKENFROMLOGGININ + "&access_type=offline");
        var response = client.DownloadString(uri);
    }

you response will have these fields 
{
"issued_to": "",
 "audience": "",
 "user_id": "",
 "scope": "",
 "expires_in": 756,
 "email": "",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "online"
}

Then you could make another call to get more personal information 

var userInfoUri = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo");
                    var userInfoClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + YOUACCESSToken);

and you will receive an object like this 

{
 "id": "",
 "name": "",
 "given_name": "",
 "family_name": "",
 "link": "",
 "picture": "",`enter code here`
 "locale": "en"
}
```